# Partition visability

Tags: disk, 17.04

I recently install ubuntu17 .  My `/` partition and the other visible drive(partition) on the machine are only visible form `+ Other Locations`  [image: this is how it looks]

I remembered this was not the case with earlier version I had, I want to save my self from the extra clicks just to enter `+ Other Locations` to be able access to this drives. is there a way I can get it to be visible 
[image: as shown here] ?

Or maybe I made a mistake during the installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the directory of the drives you want to be visible. Clicking on the `menu icon` there is an option to `Bookmark This Location`.

[image]

This will allow the drives or whatever folder to visible form `Files main window`.

[image]